# Session variable is not sent in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, session-variables

I have a Laravel Application, and something strange is happening related to the session variables. I have a method in a controller that checks some inputs and depending of some conditions it decides if continues or just return back (and right here where is my problem), when I make `return redirect()->back()` I want so send a variable that is a Json, so briefly I have this:

```
$msg=json_encode([
     'status' => 'failed',
     'field'=>'mail'
 ]);
return redirect()->back()->with('msg',$msg);
```

So, it redirects very well, but then in the view I have:

```
@if ( Session::has('msg') )
   //come stuffs
@endif
```

But it seems likes the `msg` variable is not passed. According to the Laravel documentation when one uses `redirect back` the variables are accesible trough `Session`

Comment: Watch your access log.  This is flashing the data only for the next request and if whatever page you are redirecting back to is also redirecting somewhere, you will end up losing that data.

Answer (score 1):

Its' working for me when I tested.
Maybe your session is not storing data. Please check whether your session is working or not.
My tested output

```
   @if ( Session::has('msg') )
       {{ session('msg') }}
    @endif
```

[image]

Comment: yes, just checking is probably that the problem is because I'm using the web middleware

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem on a project a while back with Laravel 5.2. I don't know if it is a bug or whether it has been fixed but I ended up getting around it by not using `redirect()->back()`. I think it might be related to the browser's caching mechanism. I would be interested if you end up finding the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` before you initiate the redirect

read the documentation at [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data)

Comment: could you do something like `if (isset( $request->session()->get( 'key' ))) {}`

Comment: yes, I wrote it just after put `$request->session()->put('key', 'value');` and it exist, but then in the view it doesnt exist anymore

Comment: you should put the if statement in your view

Comment: uhhh ok, `undefined variable $request`

Comment: but I tried `@if (! Session::has('message') )` and it entered, so it's not saving the Session variable

Comment: are your other session variables being set or is this the first time you are using it